# Can I control motion tween speed according to timer?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tween

I want to make simple motion tween of analog timer seconds arrow. Can i sync it with specified defined timer on AS3?

I know that the regular speed of animation can variate according to system specs. Any suggestions?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: I have one: Don't use motion tweens.  Use ActionScript and set a Timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your requirements, I suggest that pure actionscript would be the way to go.

Your arrow should be a movieclip. With actionscript, we can change the rotation of the movieclip to make it rotate around like an analog clock. Frames are not a good way to keep track of time, so timers are the way to go.

Here's some sample code:

```
var secondTimer:Timer;
public function Arrow() {
    secondTimer = new Timer(1000); //1 second
    secondTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tickTock);
}
private function tickTock(e:TimerEvent){
    rotation += 6; //360 degrees, 60 seconds. 1 second = 6 degrees
}
```